とでも言おうか? What does it mean here?

すると急に真崎が立ち上がった。恨みがましい目とでも言おうか、細められた視線が落ちてくる。

すると急に真崎が立ち上がった suddenly Masaki stood up.
恨みがましい目とでも言おうか、細められた視線が落ちてくる。
however what does this apart mean?
With  reproachful eyes.... the narrowed gaze falls down?


と: quotative particle
でも: maybe; something like; or something else
言おう: volitional form of 言う ("to call/say")
か: expresses uncertainty

The combination yields "I would call (it) something like ～, perhaps?"

恨みがましい目とでも言おうか、細められた視線が落ちてくる。
Eyes that could be called reproachful, perhaps — a narrowed gaze descends towards me.

